# Maybe opencv and numpy hates each other?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

I was doing some exercise with opencv and numpy. My goal was adding two gray scale images. So I made threshold function, resizing function, and white background function.

The thing is, I got into a weird problem. If

`print(a==b,c==d)` are all `True` (numpy array), obviously

`print(a*c==b*d)` is `True`, right? But it seems to be not working on my code.

Below is my code and printed value:

code:

```
from yeah import *

a = np.array([255,255,255])

g_clef = cv2.imread('g-clef.png')
g_clef = clean(g_clef)
g_clef = resize(g_clef, 0.5)
g_clef = whitebg(230,400, 20, 0, g_clef)[0][0]

whole_note = cv2.imread('whole-note.png')
whole_note = clean(whole_note) 
whole_note = resize(whole_note,0.05)
whole_note = whitebg(230,400, 20, 0, whole_note)[0][0]

print(g_clef==a)
print(1)
print(whole_note==a)
print(2)
print(g_clef*whole_note==a*a)
```

printed value:

```
[ True  True  True]
1
[ True  True  True]
2
[False False False]

ps. g_clef*whole_note=[1,1,1]
```

Comment: Can you provide the values for `g_clef` and `whole_note`?

Comment: @paul-shuvo Both are [255,255,255].